# Results no error: Shapefile nowhere to be found/not in workspace

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.2

I'm trying to do the most basic stuff. I have 2 shapefiles. One is municipality polygons, and the other one is a polygon based on road network (20 min commute, using service area). Whenever I try to combine these datasets (spatial join, clip, union) it instantly pops up as finished, but I get no shapefile as a result. The *Results tab* says there is no problem.

I checked the coordinate system etc, it's the same in both.

It says: Level of comparison between projection files: NONE. I don't know if this might be the problem.

I am using ArcGIS 10.2

Comment: what software are you using?

Comment: Im using ArcGIS 10.2

Comment: Check that you don't have a selection when you run your analysis.

Comment: Shapefiles can have polygon topology errors. Have you checked/repaiered topology?